# How to remove " 's" in a string?

Tags: r, regex, string

I am going through strings of data for instagram usernames, I have been able to use regex to remove almost all unnecessary characters. I can't figure out how to remove the " 's " trailing the words.

I am able to remove every other special character with regex. I either can remove the apostrophe and not the s, or just skip over it entirely.

#### follower.list

```
[1] "@kyrieirving’s" "@jaytatum0"    
> follower.list <- gsub("[^[:alnum:][:blank:]@_]", "", follower.list)
```

#### follower.list

```
[1] "@kyrieirvings" "@jaytatum0"
```

#### Expected:

```
[1] "@kyrieirving" "@jaytatum0"
```

Comment: If it's always going to be "'s", you may try something like `,s|[^\w\s@]`. Otherwise, try `,.*$|[^\w\s@]`. Are you sure whitespace characters are allowed though?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `'s` not `,s`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
['’]s\b|[^[:alnum:][:blank:]@_]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EkwTEs/1).

**Details**

- `['’]s\b` - `'` or `’` and then `s` at the end of a word
- `|` - or
- `[^[:alnum:][:blank:]@_]` - any char but an alphanumeric, horizontal whitespace, `@` or `_` char

[R demo](https://ideone.com/5akmdI):

```
> x <- c("@kyrieirving’s", "@jaytatum0")
> gsub("['’]s\\b|[^[:alnum:][:blank:]@_]", "",x)
[1] "@kyrieirving" "@jaytatum0"
```

Comment: @r2evans R demo is there in the answer to show how literal string should look like in a string literal.

Comment: Odd, I see it isn't "edited" but I *swear* the "R demo" wasn't there initially. Sorry, that must have been a pre-caffeine comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
follower.list = c("@kyrieirving’s", "@jaytatum0")
gsub("\\’s$",'',follower.list)
```

Comment: `’` is not a special regex metacharacter, there is no need escaping it.

Comment: my first try was with '

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, if we'd use a word boundary, the problem might be solved:

```
(@\b[A-Za-z0-9]+\b)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gdc2I1/1/)